# angularJs extend controller with binding

Tags: angularjs, binding, controller

In AngularJs I have a main controller and a template that does everything.
Now I wish to have a replicate of the same page with some added admin specific features.
I was hoping to reuse the template and extend the main controller like

```
appModule.controller('AdminController',
    function AdminCtrl($controller, $scope) {

        var vMainCtrl = $controller('MainController', {$scope: $scope});
        var vm = this;
        angular.extend(vm, vMainCtrl);

        console.log(vMainCtrl);
        console.log(vm);

    }
)
```

Problem is the MainController does some initialisation with service resources so the extend statement for vm doesn't carry over the binding of the data updates.
Whilst vMainCtrl shows the updated values how can I merge the 2 controllers into vm whilst keeping the binding in the MainController active?

Whilst the resource call is from a service it's called during the initialization of the MainController and I would like to keep that as is and just add admin features with a separate page.

Thanks

Comment: Is es6 an option for you? If so, this would probably be a lot easier with es6 classes.

Comment: es6  is not an option for me at this moment in time :-(